# How to change profile name in Dirt 3?

Tags: dirt-3

So i just started Dirt 3 up for the first time and for some reason I can't edit my name and surname in the profile (it's stuck on Name: Player, Surname: One)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

You have to press **Enter** on your name and your surname for you to be able to edit it.